# Python Multiprocessing: Writing to file every k iterations

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, file-writing

I am using the `multiprocessing` module in `python 3.7` to call a function repeatedly in parallel. I would like to write the results out to a file every *k* iterations. (It can be a different file each time.)

Below is my first attempt, which basically loops over sets of function arguments, running each set in parallel and writing the results to a file before moving onto the next set. This is obviously very inefficient. In practice, the time it takes for my function to run is much longer and varies depending on the input values, so many processors sit idle between iterations of the loop.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def myfunction(x): # toy example function
  return(x**2)

for start in np.arange(0,500,100):
    
    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        out = pool.map(myfunction, np.arange(start, start+100))
    
    pd.DataFrame(out).to_csv('filename_'+str(start//100+1)+'.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first comment is that if `myfunction` is a trivial as the one you have shown, then your performance will be worse using multiprocessing because there is overhead in creating the process pool (which by the way you are unnecessarily creating over and over in each loop iteration) and passing arguments from one process to another.

Assuming that `myfunction` is pure CPU and after `map` has returned 100 values there is an opportunity to overlap the writing of the CSV files that you are not taking advantage of (it's not clear how much performance will be improved by concurrent disk writing; it depends on the type of drive you have, head movement, etc.), then a combination of multithreading and multiprocessing could be the solution. The number of processes in your processing pool will be limited to the number of CPU cores given the assumption that `myfunction` is 100% CPU and does not release the Global Interpreter Lock and therefore cannot take advantage of a pool size greater than the number of CPUs you have. Anyway, that is my assumption. If you are going to be using certain `numpy` functions for example, then that is an erroneous assumption. On the other hand, it is known that `numpy` uses multiprocessing for some of its own processing in which case the combination of using `numpy` and your own multiprocessing could result in worse performance. Your current code is only using `numpy` for generating ranges. This seems to be a bit of overkill as there are other means of generating ranges. I have taken the liberty of generating the ranges in a slightly different fashion by defining `START` and `STOP` values and `N_SPLITS`, the number of equal (or as equally as possible) divisions of this range as possible and generating tuples of start and stop values that can be converted into ranges. I hope this is not too confusing. But this seemed to be a more flexible approach.

In the following code both a thread pool and a processing pool are created. The tasks are submitted to the thread pool with one of the arguments being the processing pool, whish is used by the worker to do the CPU intensive calculations and then when the results have been assembled the worker writes out the CSV file.

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool, ThreadPool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
import pandas as pd

def worker(process_pool, index, split_range):
    out = process_pool.map(myfunction, range(*split_range))
    pd.DataFrame(out).to_csv(f'filename_{index}.csv', header=False, index=False)

def myfunction(x): # toy example function
  return(x ** 2)

def split(start, stop, n):
    k, m = divmod(stop - start, n)
    return [(i * k + min(i, m),(i + 1) * k + min(i + 1, m)) for i in range(n)]

def main():
    RANGE_START = 0
    RANGE_STOP = 500
    N_SPLITS = 5
    n_processes = min(N_SPLITS, cpu_count())
    split_ranges = split(RANGE_START, RANGE_STOP, N_SPLITS) # [(0, 100), (100, 200), ... (400, 500)]
    process_pool = Pool(n_processes)
    thread_pool = ThreadPool(N_SPLITS)
    for index, split_range in enumerate(split_ranges):
        thread_pool.apply_async(worker, args=(process_pool, index, split_range))
    # wait for all threading tasks to complete:
    thread_pool.close()
    thread_pool.join()

# required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```